# How to color the edges of a triangle?

Tags: graphics, polygons

I'd like to draw a triangle (given the side lengths) with the sides colored separately.

I tried 
`Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[0]], EdgeForm[Blue], SSSTriangle[2, 2, 3]}]`

giving:

[image: my try]

But I want to color the edges separately, eg Blue, Green and Red.

Comment: Pretty sure the only way is to make the graphic using individual lines.

Comment: What about using `Graph`?

Answer (score 6):

I was going to do the same as george2079 (+1). I'll post it on account of having used a rather different programming style.

```
colorTriangle[Triangle[{pt1_, pt2_, pt3_}], {c1_, c2_, c3_}] := {
  c1, Line[{pt1, pt2}],
  c2, Line[{pt2, pt3}],
  c3, Line[{pt3, pt1}]
  }

Graphics[{
  colorTriangle[SSSTriangle[2, 2, 3], {Red, Green, Blue}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Coloring it so that particular colors correspond to particular side lengths is more difficult, but here's one way:

```
SetAttributes[colorTriangle, HoldFirst]
colorTriangle[SSSTriangle[l1_, l2_, l3_], {c1_, c2_, c3_}] := Module[{allTriangles, wellOrderedQ, wellOrderedTriangles},
  allTriangles = SSSTriangle[l1, l2, l3] /. Triangle[{pt1_, pt2_, pt3_}] :> Permutations[{
       Line[{pt1, pt2}], Line[{pt2, pt3}], Line[{pt3, pt1}]
       }];

  wellOrderedQ = allTriangles /. {Line[{pt11_, pt12_}], Line[{pt21_, pt22_}], Line[{pt31_, pt32_}]} :> And[
      Norm[pt11 - pt12] == l1,
      Norm[pt21 - pt22] == l2,
      Norm[pt31 - pt32] == l3
      ];

  wellOrderedTriangles = Pick[allTriangles, wellOrderedQ, True];

  Graphics@Riffle[{Red, Green, Blue}, #] & /@ wellOrderedTriangles
  ]
```

Since there aren't always one unique way to color a triangle in this fashion the result is a list of up to six triangles:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looking good! But the edge lengths are in a different order to their colors!

Comment: @pdmclean That criterion complicates the problem significantly and should have been mentioned in the question... Anyway, I've posted an update about that now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make this more difficult than it has to be,

```
HighlightMesh[
 DiscretizeGraphics@SSSTriangle[2, 2, 3], {Style[{2, 1}, White]}~
  Join~({Style[{1, {#}}, Thick, {Red, Green, Blue}[[#]]] & /@ 
     Range[3]})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 posted similar thing but was 1 min late :) I was struggling with 2D component because usually `Style` `None` works but here it breaks everything and `White` saves the day,

Comment: @Kuba - I was trying for `Style[.., Opacity[0]]` but I couldn't get it to work..

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics[Transpose[{{Red, Green, Blue}, SSSTriangle[2, 2, 3] /.
     Triangle[li_] :> Line /@ Partition[Append[li, li[[1]]], 2, 1] }]]
```

[image]

Comment: Vastly simpler: `Graphics[Riffle[{Red, Green, Blue}, Map[Line, Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & @@ SSSTriangle[2, 2, 3]]]]`